# how to create dropdown hint in cakePHP 3 but still able to add own

Tags: cakephp-3.0

how to create dropdown hint in cakePHP 3 but still able to add my own string?

I know how to create dropdown field with options:

```
$this->Form->control('category',array('options' => $categories));
```

In this I cannot add my new value to field. Is it possible to also have dropdown/combobox/hint and able to add new value? 
Thank you for advise.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript library for hint in your CTP file

```
$this->Form->control('category',array(class=>"select2" 'options' => $categories));
```

in your template file add js library 
and below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```